# How to see Bullet logs in Sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob, bullet

Is there any way of seeing Bullet logs while the work is processed in Sidekiq worker? When I perform N+1 query in Sidekiq worker (through ActiveJob queue adapter) I don't see the usual Bullet log in neither the Rails console nor the Sidekiq console.

Comment: Do you have `Bullet.rails_logger = true` in your bullet config?

Comment: Yes I have it enabled. The problem is that when Sidekiq worker takes over, nothing what the worker does is printed in the rails server log.

Comment: But when i perform the N+1 query in the Rails controller, before I actually call the worker I can see the Bullet log in rails server as usual.

Comment: Any solutions yet? @MartinSvoboda

Comment: I don't recall solving this issue. :(

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

As they explain in the [docs](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet#work-with-other-background-job-solution), you can use `Bullet.profile`:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  around_perform do |_job, block|
    Bullet.profile do
      block.call
    end
  end
end
```